# Trying to send an email using Swiftmailer

Tags: php, forms, validation, swiftmailer

I've been struggling for four days to send a validation email to a new user through a PHP function. Then i tried to send a simple email!

Just a few clarifications needed:

- Must we put the name of the user or that of the full address on the Gmail server? Several sounds of bells ...
- who can explain to me in a few words the \ in the line "$ message = (new \ Swift_Message ('Email Through Swift Mailer'))"?
- define ('EMAIL', 'constant;: Does this function work well with PDO and PHP 7? It seems that using
  const EMAIL_USERNAME = 'constant'; works better.

Until then this script still doesn't work:

```
<?php

require 'dev.php';

require 'C:wamp64/www/dayou_php/vendor/autoload.php';


echo 'Envoi de mail avec Swift Mailer';

$subject = 'Mon premier email avec Swift Mailer';

$fromEmail = 'sixxerxxre@gmail.com';

$fromUser = '思而惹';

$body = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mon premier mail</title>
</head>
<body>
<h5>Hello SwiftMailer</h5>
</body>
</html>';


$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT))

->setUsername(EMAIL_USERNAME)

->setPassword(EMAIL_PASSWORD)

->setEncryption(EMAIL_ENCRYPTION) //For Gmail

;


// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);


// Create a message

 $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))

->setFrom([$fromEmail => $fromUser])

->setTo([EMAIL_USERNAME])

->setBody($body, 'text/html')

;


 // Send the message

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Variables are in another script *dev.php*:

```
const EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// autre port possibles : 465 pour ssl

const EMAIL_PORT = 587;
const EMAIL_USERNAME = 'my_username_without_@gmail';

const EMAIL_PASSWORD = 'my_pass_word';

// autre possibilité : ssl ou null

const EMAIL_ENCRYPTION = 'tls';
```

The error I get is about the constant *my_username_without_@gmail*:

```
Address in mailbox given [seeergefaure] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. in C:\wamp64\www\dayou_php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php on line 355
```

Answer (score 0):

> we must put the name of the user or that of the full address on the
> gmail server? several sounds of bells ...

You need to put full name with @gmail.com

> who can explain to me in a few words the \ in the line "$ message =
> (new \ Swift_Message ('Email Through Swift Mailer'))"?

It's about name spaces. It means, that you use global namespace (it will be used from your autoloader).

> define ('EMAIL', 'constant;: Does this function work well with PDO and
> php 7? it seems that using const EMAIL_USERNAME = 'constant'; works
> better.

The basic difference between define and const is that const defines constants at compile time, whereas define() defines them at run time.

Your code looks good.

Comment: Thank you so much ! after modified userame by adding @gmail it works fine !  but when i tried to exchange the two emails, this was not working and gave me an error of identification in the file  =>    vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\Esmtp\AuthHandler.php on line 191   __with =>   Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: You want send email to two different emails?

Comment: no !  :-) i try to get validation email from a form, so there are one sender ( the user ) and a recever ( me in my gmail account ), so i made try from another gmail account ( of me ).  This is google temselves who were the problem  :  Tentative de connexion bloquée pour votre compte Google associé
 sixxerxxre@gmail.com  so they blocked my php script :-(  this is what i call paranoia.    Great thanks to U